# ngDisabled validation not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to add a single disabled="disabled" to a button, to block the element while the it is creating a server requests, however, for some reason the documentations information is not working for me, so my case is:

```
 HTML:
 <button ng-disabled="isDisable" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>

 JS (into my controller):
 $scope.isDisable = false;

 $scope.submit = function() {
    $scope.isDisable = true;

    //$http request.... 
    something.sucess(function(data) {
       $scope.isDisable = false;
    };
 };
```

for some reason my logic is not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: you have a typo in success... something.success. Is it being disabled but not re-enabled? If so, that will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `{{}}` as it's not an expression.

```
 <button ng-disabled="isDisable" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
```

**EDIT**

If this is a form then on the form tag do ..

```
<form name="aForm" novalidate ng-submit="submit()">
```

then submit button

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="isDisable">Submit</button>
```

Comment: I just realized that, however it is still not working